# if statement to see if not empty or if not 0000-00-00

Tags: php

I am trying to make this if statement do the following. If the POST is empty or if it has 0000-00-00 in it I want to set $paid to 0 but if there is a date in POST set paid to 1. I do not think I have this correct

```
if (!empty($_POST['paiddate'])| if($_POST['paiddate'] != 0000-00-00)
{
    $paid = 1;
} else
{
    $paid = 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `|` for your conditional statement and remove the second `if` plus a missing `)`

Comment: Plus, you may want to use quotes inside `!= 0000-00-00` as in `!= "0000-00-00"` because of the `-` signs (minus).

Comment: `if (!empty($_POST['paiddate']) || ($_POST['paiddate'] != "0000-00-00"))` as it stands, you have 2x `if`s and 1x `else`

Comment: If this is even remotely connected to the website your profile links to … then any possible customer can only be warned to stay the hell away from that service, as long as you’re operating on such a level of “knowledge” … this is a liability lawsuit waiting to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few errors with your code.

1. There is a redundant `if` statement.
2. AND and OR operations are written like this: `a && b` and `a || b`.
3. Strings are enclosed in quotes. 0000-00-00 should be a string.

So your code becomes:

```
if (!empty($_POST['paiddate']) || $_POST['paiddate'] != '0000-00-00')
{
    $paid = 1;
}
else
{
    $paid = 0;
}
```

You may further enhance it with a *ternary operator*:

```
$paid = !empty($_POST['paiddate']) || $_POST['paiddate'] != '0000-00-00' ? 1 : 0;
```

If you're using `$paid` later within a `if ($paid)`, you may further shorten this to:

```
$paid = !empty($_POST['paiddate']) || $_POST['paiddate'] != '0000-00-00';
```

and if you find it more readable, access the POST array only once:

```
$paidDate = $_POST['paiddate'];
$paid = !empty($paidDate) || $paidDate != '0000-00-00';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be refactored like this:

```
if ((isset($_POST['paid date']) && !empty($_POST['paid date'])) || $_POST['paid date'] != '0000-00-00') {
  $paid = 1;
}
else {
  $paid = 0;
}
```

Note how I added an `isset()` to `!empty()` which checks if `_POST['paid date']` is set in the array & is not empty. Also you `|` would never work. Also `0000-00-00` needs to have single quotes (`'0000-00-00'`) for it to work as a string value and not the odd equation of 0000 minus 00 minus 00. Finally, it needs to be `||` for proper `or` syntax. Also this compound `if` conditional structure is 100% incorrect:

```
if ([something]) || if([another thing])
```

It should always be in one `if` conditional like this (and as edited in my code reworking):

```
if ([something] || [another thing])
```

I also don’t understand your larger logic but I would recommend using boolean `TRUE`/`FALSE` logic instead like this:

```
if ((isset($_POST['paid date']) && !empty($_POST['paid date'])) || $_POST['paiddate'] != '0000-00-00') {
  $paid = TRUE;
}
else {
  $paid = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Next thing: `$a = ''; var_dump(isset($a));`

Comment: You told: `Note how I changed !empty() to isset() which checks if _POST['paid date'] is set in the array & is not empty` This is not true. `isset()` checks only if the value was set and is not `NULL`. If it is set and the value is an empty string, `0`, `array()`, `false` or whatever, then `isset()` will return `true`. But this is not desired here.

Comment: If you leave a text field in a web form empty, then it's value will be sent as `''` (an empty string). `isset()` would return `true` in this case but this is not desired.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use if statements in that way. Standard method

```
if ((condition 1) || (condtion 2)) 
{
some code 
}
```

Here is the solution.

```
if ( !empty($_POST['paiddate']) || ($_POST['paiddate'] != "0000-00-00" ))
{
    $paid = 1;
} else
{
    $paid = 0;
}
```